# Python type hinting merging two lists of classes that subclass the same class

Tags: python, python-3.x, subclass, type-hinting, false-positive

I have two classes, `Foo` and `Bar` that both subclass `A`. I want to merge two lists of the respective subclasses into one list of type `list[A]` while keeping the type hinting intact.
I expect the following examples to work:

```
class A: pass
class Foo(A): pass
class Bar(A): pass
foo_list = [Foo(), Foo()]
bar_list = [Bar(), Bar(), Bar()]
# Attempt 1
tmp1 = foo_list + bar_list
# Attempt 2
tmp2: list[A] = foo_list + bar_list
```

But they all give the following warning on the `bar_list` (in the Pycharm IDE):
`Expected type 'list[Foo]' (matched generic type 'list[_T]'), got 'list[Bar]' instead.`
It looks like the type system specializes `foo_List` to `list[Foo]` too early which prevents it from understanding that it should also function as a valid `list[A]` expression.

I found some workarounds, but they're two-liners and impractical:

```
tmp3 = foo_list.copy()
tmp3 += bar_list  # Not sure why this is allowed if the above examples aren't

tmp4: list[A] = foo_list.copy()
tmp4 = tmp4 + bar_list
```

Why are these warnings thrown, and more importantly, how can I work around them without disabling the warning in its entirety or ignoring the warning on every occurrence?

Comment: You've identified why they're thrown - the two lists you're concatenating are typed as `list[Foo]` and `list[Bar]`, which are incompatible with one another, not `list[A]`. `_: list[A] = [Foo(), Bar()]` would work, for example. Or `_ : list[A] = [Foo()]` then `_.append(Bar())`, which also saves one unnecessary list creation (note using `_` for a variable you intend to use makes the example quite confusing).

Comment: @jonrsharpe I edited the post to reflect that I don't have the luxury of creating the lists. I'm merging two existing lists, so I can't use `_: list[A] = [Foo(), Bar()]`. This also means that append is unfortunately not an option.

Comment: Then you're probably going to have to manually widen them (with e.g. `left: list[A] = one_thing` and `right: list[A] = the_other`) before you concatenate them (`left + right`). Python doesn't currently provide a way to have inline type hints within an expression, as far as I'm aware (c.f. TypeScript: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions).